# Why does OpenAI's PPO algorithm not follow the discounting method used in Sutton & Barto?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, proximal-policy-optimization, sutton-barto, discount-factor

As discussed in [this question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/7680/2444), the policy gradient algorithms given in [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf) use the gradient
\begin{align*} 
\gamma^t \hat A_t \nabla_{\theta} \log \pi(a_t \, | \, s_t, \theta)
\end{align*}
where $\hat A_t$ is the advantage estimate for step $t$. For example, $\hat A_t = r_t + \gamma V(s_{t+1}) - V(s_t)$ in the one-step actor-critic algorithm given in section 13.5.

In the answers to the linked question, it is claimed that the extra discounting is "correct", which implies that it should be included.

If I look in the literature to a seminal paper such as [Proximal Policy Optimization Algorithms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06347) by OpenAI, they do not include the extra discounting factor, i.e. they use a gradient defined as
\begin{align*} 
\hat A_t \dfrac{\nabla_{\theta}\pi(a_t \, | \, s_t, \theta)}{\pi(a_t \, | \,s_t, \theta_{\rm old})}
\end{align*}
which does not include the discounting factor (of course, it's dealing with the off-policy case, but I don't see how that would make a difference in terms of the discounting). [OpenAI's implementation of PPO](https://github.com/openai/baselines/tree/master/baselines/ppo2) also does not include the extra discounting factor.

So, how am I supposed to interpret this discrepancy? I agree that the extra discounting factor should be present, from a theoretical standpoint. Then, why is it not in the OpenAI code or paper?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maximize the expected reward
\begin{align*} 
\mathbb{E}\bigg[\sum_{t=1}^nr_t \bigg]
\end{align*}
and are using a score function based gradient estimator (as opposed to a SAC/DDPG style update), you have the unbiased gradient estimator
\begin{align*} 
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=i}^n r_k\nabla_{\theta}\log\pi(a_t) \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Then, you can add discounting as a variance reduction technique; the gradient estimator
\begin{align*} 
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=i}^n \gamma^{k-i}r_k\nabla_{\theta}\log\pi(a_t) \tag{2}
\end{align*}
will have a lower variance than Eq. (1) (see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/428157/257864)).

If you want to maximize the discounted expected reward
\begin{align*} 
\mathbb{E}\bigg[\sum_{t=1}^n \gamma^{t-1}r_t \bigg]
\end{align*}
you get the unbiased gradient estimator
\begin{align*} 
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=i}^n \gamma^{k-1}r_k\nabla_{\theta}\log\pi(a_t) \tag{3}
\end{align*}
So in Sutton and Barto they are essentially presenting the formulation Eq. (3). The difference between (2) and (3) is the factor of $\gamma^{i-1}$ which is what I was confused about in the question.

Thus in summary, the formulation (2) is an biased estimator of the expected reward; whereas (3) is an unbiased estimator of the expected discounted reward.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you will find the answer in the paper [High-Dimensional Continuous Control Using Generalized Advantage Estimation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02438), which is the basis for the advantage function used in the PPO paper that you referenced.

From the paper, the estimate of the advantage function is defined as:
\begin{align*}
\hat{A}_{t}^{GAE(\gamma,\lambda)} = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(\gamma\lambda)^{l}\delta_{t+1}^{V}
\end{align*}
where $\delta_{t}^{V}$, the TD residual of $V$, is defined as:
\begin{align*}
\delta_{t}^{V} = r_{t}+\gamma V(s_{t+1})-V(s_{t})
\end{align*}
where $V$ is an approximate of the value function.

If you look closely at these two equations you will see that the discount $\gamma$ is applied twice.

I never went through the code of the whole OpenAI implementation of PPO, but if I am not mistaken the implementation of the above equations can be found [here in ppo2/runner.py](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/ea25b9e8b234e6ee1bca43083f8f3cf974143998/baselines/ppo2/runner.py#L63-L64).

Comment: This does not answer the question. I am familiar with GAE and the equations you give are consistent with the PPO paper. The question is whether or not it is supposed to be $\gamma^{t-1}\hat A_t$ (which is what Sutton and Barto give and what I would expect accordingly to theory); or whether it should be just $\hat A_t$, which is what is present in the PPO paper, PPO code, and GAE paper.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear in my answer. From my understanding of the GAE and PPO implementation, the discount factor is there twice like in S&B, it is just not applied in the same order.

Comment: You have given the definition of $\hat A_t$. I agree with the definition. The question is whether the gradient of the (log probability) should use the coefficient $\hat A_t$ or $\gamma^{t-1} \hat A_t$.

Comment: No, I don't believe that $\gamma$ should be applied to the gradient in $\hat{A}_{t}\frac{\nabla_{\theta}\pi(a_t \, | \, s_t, \theta)}{\pi(a_t \, | \,s_t, \theta_{\rm old})}$ for the reason that it is applied in the calculation of the estimate of the advantage and in the calculation of $\delta^{V}_{t}$ .